# категории и подкатегории

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Мне нужно сделать чтоб к моделе Post можна добавить категории у которых есть подкатегории. Например категории дома, квартиры ...итд, и подкат аренда, посуточно, продажа. Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать!

models category.rb

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
end
```

категории создавал в seeds, а как к ним добавить подкатегории?

```
Category.where(name: "Дома").first_or_create(name: "Дома")  
Category.where(name: "Квартиры").first_or_create(name: "Квартиры")
```

форма

```
 <%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories), :prompt => "Категория") %>
```

Comment: Для начала надо определиться, как вы будете их представлять в базе. Это нужно определить исходя из того, какие запросы на категории вы планируете к базе совершать.

Comment: Я не понял о каких вы запросах. (не так давно изучаю RoR) Когда пользователь будет создавать пост ему должны быть доступны теже категории и подкат. Потом по категориях будет реализирован поиск, при выборе той или иной категории должны отображатся соответствующие категориям посты.

Comment: RoR тут вообще ни при чём, вам нужна модель данных для СУБД, которой планируете пользоваться. Вам для этого надо знать, какие запросы к этим данным вы собираетесь делать. Для запроса отдельных категорий, скажем, достаточно первичного ключа, тут всё очевидно. Что ещё? Категорию и её непосредственные подкатегории? Категорию и рекурсивно все подкатегории?

Answer (score 0):

Вообще если уровень вложенности больше 2, то лучше категориии организовать в виде nested sets. 
Для этого есть гем https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set,
но вообще лучше с самим паттерном ознакомиться. С его помощью можно, например, дергать все подкатегории без рекурсии